# setsockopt() for a raw socket fd failed

Tags: c++, c, sockets, raw-sockets

## Description:

I use:

```
int syn_socket = (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

to create a **raw socket**, I have **root privilege**. And then:

```
int on = 1;
int rc = setsockopt(syn_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on));
```

`setsockopt` returns `-1`, and `errno` is `EBADF`. And here is the log:

> [ 2016-12-05 11:02:34 UTC ] [ syn.cpp:266 ] [ syn ] create raw
>   socket (255)
>  [ 2016-12-05 11:02:34 UTC ] [ syn.cpp:220 ] [
>   send_syn_packet ] setsockopt(255) failed. (Ba d file descriptor)
>  [
>   2016-12-05 11:02:34 UTC ] [ syn.cpp:292 ] [ syn ] send syn
>   packet failed.

Comment: You need to _call_ `socket()`.

Comment: When you call socket, the system will create a socket for you and then return a filedescriptor, so that your program can access the correct socket.

From the man-page socket:  int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
 int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);

Comment: OMG, how stupid mistake I have made!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int syn_socket = (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

As @DaV already hinted at, this is not calling `socket()`. The word `socket` is absent from that line. It compiles, because it is still valid C. If you write:

```
int a = (1, 2, 3);
```

The result is that `a` is set to the value 3. Your `syn_socket` is set to `IPPROTO_RAW`, which is equivalent to 255, which indeed most likely is not a valid descriptor.

You need to call `socket()`:

```
int syn_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```